# OpenMP: Locking access to single array elements?

Tags: c, openmp

I'm fairly new to OpenMP, so this may have an easy answer, but I haven't been able to find it.

Suppose I have the following C code and want to parallelize it using OpenMP. A is an array of objects which have some double value less than 1 buckets is an array of linked lists, and append adds a pointer to an object to the end fo a linked list.

```
#pragma omp for 
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x = (int) (A[i].val * NUM_BUCKETS);
    append(&A[i], buckets[x]);
}
```

The problem is that multiple threads may be trying to append items to a given bucket at one time. I could make that append statement critical. However, in my application, I'll probably have ~1000 buckets or so, so the large majority of the time the threads will be operating on different buckets.

Is there a way to enforce locks on the individual elements of buckets? Or some other way of handling this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, OpenMP can't do it for you automatically, but it lets you create your own lock variables which you can use to limit access to array elements; for instance, you could have one lock per array element:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int NITEMS=20;
    int array[NITEMS];
    omp_lock_t lock[NITEMS];

    for (int i=0; i<NITEMS; i++)
        omp_init_lock(&(lock[i]));

#pragma omp parallel for shared(array, lock) default(none)
     for (int i=0; i<NITEMS; i++) {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int item = (i * 7) % NITEMS;

        omp_set_lock(&(lock[item]));
        array[item] = tid;    // only one thread in here at a time; others block at set_lock()
        omp_unset_lock(&(lock[item]));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NITEMS; i++)
        printf("%3d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (int i=0; i<NITEMS; i++)
        omp_destroy_lock(&(lock[i]));


    return 0;
}
```

Or, if that level of granularity were more than you needed, you could block regions of the array, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan What if NITEMS value is not known beforehand? It seems omp_lock_t lock[NITEMS] requires a constant number before compiling the code...

Comment: @Ash you'd just allocate a dynamically-sized array of them; `omp_lock_t *lock = (omp_lock_t *) malloc(nitems*sizeof(omp_lock_t));`or so.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP does not provide fine grained locking. You can prepare the new list element, e.g. by setting its `next` pointer to `NULL` and use `atomic` to guard the update of the list tail pointer. This is as fine as you can get with current OpenMP implementations.

Of course since OpenMP uses the underlying OS threading primitives you can use whatever locking the latter provides, e.g. use an array of `pthreads` mutexes for each bucket. The downside is that it creates unportable applications but if efficiency is more important you might be willing to sacrifice the portability.